# Parsing strings with Scheme

Tags: parsing, scheme, sxml

I am trying to write a simple parser which creates a sxml-expression from a string, e. g.

```
"This is a [Test]" ===> (item "This is a" (subitem "Test"))
```

Anybody who is wondering about the square brackets within the given example may have a look at the so called [Leiden conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiden_Conventions).

This is the code I have written so far:

```
(define my-sequence '("this" "[" "is" "a" "]" "test"))

(define (left-square-bracket? item)
  (or (equal? item "[")
      (eq? item #\x005b)))

(define (right-square-bracket? item)
  (or (equal? item "]")
      (eq? item #\x005d)))

(define (parse-sequence sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) '())
        ((left-square-bracket? (car sequence))
         (let ((subsequence (get-subsequence (cdr sequence))))
           (list subsequence)))
        (else
         (cons (car sequence)
               (parse-sequence (cdr sequence))))))

(define (get-subsequence sequence)
  (if (right-square-bracket? (car sequence))
      '()
      (cons (car sequence)
            (get-subsequence (cdr sequence)))))
```

Evaluating `(parse-sequence my-sequence)` yields `("this" ("is" "a"))`. A nested expression has been created, but the program finished without having evaluated the last item `"test"`. The question is, how do I return from `get-subsequence` to `parse-sequence`?

Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your initial questions, how to return multiple values: use the "values" form. Here is an example implementation where the inner procedure returns both the remaining list to be processed and the result so far. It recurses on opening brackets.

```
(define (parse-sequence lst)

  (define (parse-seq lst)
    (let loop ((lst lst) (res null))
      (cond
        ((null? lst) (values null res))
        ((string=? (car lst) "[")
         (let-values ([(lst2 res2) (parse-seq (cdr lst))])
           (loop lst2 (append res (list res2)))))
        ((string=? (car lst) "]")
         (values (cdr lst) res))
        (else
          (loop (cdr lst) (append res (list (car lst))))))))

  (let-values ([(lst res) (parse-seq lst)])
    res))
```

then

```
(parse-sequence '("this" "is" "a" "test"))
(parse-sequence '("this" "[" "is" "a" "]" "test"))
(parse-sequence '("this" "[" "is" "[" "a" "]" "]" "test"))
```

will yield

```
'("this" "is" "a" "test")
'("this" ("is" "a") "test")
'("this" ("is" ("a")) "test")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your alternative solution! I am pleased about that because it copes with nested brackets which I was aware of but did not address yet. Also many thanks for making me learn about SRFI 11 `let-values` and these string-predicates!

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know which Scheme implementation you use, but  if you are a beginner I would recommend Racket to you; it has many features, a great documentation and an excellent IDE. By browsing the docs you will discover many interesting and useful forms.

Comment: I am now learning scheme since 4 months, so I may be called a kind of an advanced beginner. I started with Racket as you recommended, but as I am a puristic guy I found Racked a bit overloaded and switched to guile. I am using the wonderful [geiser-mode](http://nongnu.org/geiser/) within Emacs, which is a devoted companion to me almost since 7 years now. :) I am mostly working with SICP and the R5RS/R7RS documents, this may be a reason why I miss some nice features betimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress by using `open-input-string` in combination with `read-char:`

```
(define my-sequence (open-input-string "this [is a] test"))

(define (parse-sequence sequence)
  `(item
    ,@(let loop ((next-char (read-char sequence)))
        (cond ((eof-object? next-char) '())
              ((left-square-bracket? next-char)
               (let ((subsequence (get-subsequence sequence)))
                 (cons subsequence
                       (loop (read-char sequence)))))
              (else
               (cons next-char
                     (loop (read-char sequence))))))))

(define (get-subsequence sequence)
  `(subitem
    ,@(let loop ((next-char (read-char sequence)))
        (if (right-square-bracket? next-char)
            '()
            (cons next-char
                  (loop (read-char sequence)))))))

(parse-sequence my-sequence)
===> (item #\t #\h #\i #\s #\space (subitem #\i #\s #\space #\a) #\space #\t #\e #\s #\t)
```

Now work goes on, step by step. :)

Any comments and suggestions are still appreciated. :)